# Are bits significant in endianness?

Tags: c++, c++11, endianness

I'm attempting to handle endianness in a cross-platform C++11 application.

Suppose I'd like to convert a 64-bit value from big endian to little endian with *well-defined* behavior. One resource suggests I could load the big endian version into `std::bitset` and reverse the contents.

But that isn't correct, is it? Endianness seems to always deal with byte order, not bit order, but I can't find a definitive resource that explicitly addresses the matter.

Comment: remove that "one resource" from your bookmarks

Comment: Why do you want to convert from one order to the other? A much more common use case is to _read_ a value from a _big endian byte stream_ into a _native_ `uint64_t`.

Comment: @RolandIllig That is the use case at hand. Streaming or converting, this was meant to be a theoretical question.

Comment: Resources don't address the matter because you can't address a bit.  So you can't get it wrong either.

Comment: @HansPassant But you certainly can address bits with `std::bitset`. Unless I misunderstand.

Comment: That's done in software, not hardware.  The & operator does not have an endiness problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely right.

If endianness is shown by the representation of the value `0x12345678`, then big endian is `12 34 56 78` and little endian is `78 56 34 12`. Reversing the bits in the big endian representation would not produce the little endian representation, only reversing the bytes would.